# WebSockets TLS ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, wpf, ssl, websocket, wss

I have a WPF app running as a "Server" which sends data to the browser via WebSockets
The "Server" sends this data over `http://localhost:8181` to my website succesfully.

The problem is: I recently updated my website to be accessible over HTTPS but now all the websockets requests are blocked because it isn't secure. `ws://localhost:8181.`

I changed the server to send the data over TLS (`https://localhost:8443`) and my website to receive the sockets via wss://localhost:8443.

But now I always get the following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8443/MyData/stream' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to *

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?